# Android 6 Marshmallow crash while calling native library

Tags: java, android

My app uses native library, and no problem from Android 2.2 to 5.1

But on Android 6 Marshmallow app crashes with error: E/AndroidRuntime(1602): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.ipc.sdk.FSApi.Init() (tried Java_com_ipc_sdk_FSApi_Init and Java_com_ipc_sdk_FSApi_Init__) at com.ipc.sdk.FSApi.Init(Native Method)

How can I fix crash?

**Update**
FSApi.java

```
   package com.ipc.sdk;
   public class FSApi 
   {
   ...  
   public static native int Init();
   ...
   static {
    try{
        System.loadLibrary("IOTCAPIs"); 
    }catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError ule)
    {
    }
    try{
        System.loadLibrary("RDTAPIs"); 
    }catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError ule){
    }
    try{
        System.loadLibrary("iconv");
        System.loadLibrary("FSApi"); 
    }catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError ule){
    }
   }
   }
```

In MainActivity I call:

```
FSApi.Init();
```

If I comment call:

```
// FSApi.Init();
```

no crash. It means that native libraries loaded succesfull. 
Also I get error in logcat:

```
No implementation found for int com.ipc.sdk.FSApi.Init() (tried Java_com_ipc_sdk_FSApi_Init and Java_com_ipc_sdk_FSApi_Init__) at com.ipc.sdk.FSApi.Init(Native Method)
```

It looks like Marshmallow tries to find Java_com_ipc_sdk_FSApi_Init or Java_com_ipc_sdk_FSApi_Init__ in the library, but without success.
But if I open .so in the text editor, I'm finding Java_com_ipc_sdk_FSApi_Init !

Problem occurs only with two conditions together:
1. android:targetSdkVersion="23" in manifest 
2. Device Android 6 Marshmallow.

On android:targetSdkVersion="22" and Android 6 Marshmallow not crashing, for android:targetSdkVersion="23" and devices before Marshmallow also not crashing.

Comment: There's no way that we can help fix this without more information. Please can you edit your question to include a minimal complete and verifiable example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Thanx, I have updated question

Comment: Does your `Init` method does something that requires any dangerous permission?

Comment: It's 3d party native library, and it requires RECORD_AUDIO and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions. Also native library uses libcrypto.so and libssl.so. I've just google that this two libraries excluded from Marshmallow! I put libcrypto.so and libssl.so in libs/armeabi and added System.loadLibrary("crypto") and System.loadLibrary("ssl"), but without result, still the same error (

Comment: @apollox In your manifeast file change targetsdk with 21 and also change Project build target with 5.1.1.
Please check.
Follow this link https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-runtime
Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem using the **Foscam SDK for Android**.

Like @135 said, you just need to change the **targetSdkVersion to 21**. Is not the best solution but it works with no crash.

I'm going to update this answer if I've found another workaround.

Comment: Thank you! I've already changed targetSdkVersion to 21, and the problem disappeared. I also tried to find another way to solve the problem, but so far without success...

Comment: @apollox No problem! Just a question, are you playing with the Foscam API for Android? Because I'm testing some code and maybe we can share some thoughts about that.

Comment: Yes, I use Foscam API for Android. My application - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.web_site.easycamera
No problem to share!

Comment: It worked for  Vuforia .so, for Marshmallow, thanks.